# Grep Number before pattern

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have file with following content

```
4 packets transmitted, 2 received, 50% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.904/1.108/1.235/0.148 ms
```

Now I am trying to find the packet loss percentage and received value

```
loss=`more file.txt  | grep "% packet loss" | awk -v RS=[0-9]+ '{print RT+0;exit}'`
```

But it always returns me the 4 ( first number in the line). But I am expecting loss to be 50% and received to be 2

Comment: What happens when you remove the `exit` ?

Comment: It doesnt return any value

Comment: Shouldn't you use `grep -o`? (Only showing that piece of output to work with)

Comment: That also didnt work . Had tried that option .Results in empty output

Comment: When I remove the `exit` (... `| awk -v RS=[0-9]+ '{print RT+0}'`) I get 4 2 50 2002 0 (each on their own line).

Comment: my mistake i left wrong closing .

Comment: Thank you .. that works for me now with sed usage to get the variable assigned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would need to make things hard using `RS` and using `cat .. | grep` when `awk` can just solve the problem with just regex match. Just do

```
awk 'match($0, /.*([0-9]) received, ([0-9%]+)/, arr){ print "received="arr[1]; print "loss="arr[2]  }' file.txt
```

Storing it in a shell variable, e.g. on `bash` supporting process-substitution

```
read -r received loss < <(awk 'match($0, /.*([0-9]) received, ([0-9%]+)/, arr){ printf "%d %s", arr[1]+0, arr[2] ; }' file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this all you're trying to do?

```
$ awk '/% packet loss/{print $6, $4}' file
50% 2
```

and if you need them separately:

```
$ arr=( $(awk '/% packet loss/{print $6, $4}' file) )
$ echo "${arr[0]}"
50%
$ echo "${arr[1]}"
2
```